# View terminal history in VIM

Tags: vim, terminal

Is there a way to see and or search the terminal history in VIM?

Tried `:! history` and it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to see and or search the terminal history in VIM?

Yes, you can do any of the following:

- `<C-z>` to suspend Vim, `$ history` to see the history, `$ fg` to come back to Vim.
- `:shell`, then `$ history`.
- `:terminal history` or `:terminal`, then `$ history`.
- `:!bash`, then `$ history`.

By default, `:!<cmd>` executes `<cmd>` as if it was passed to the `-c` flag so `:!history` is equivalent of doing `$ bash -c history` in your shell: no history.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
:new |r !history
```

This will split your window and pipe the output from !history into the new window.

Comment: With Vim trying to expand the `%` to the current file I don't think that command does what you think it does.

Comment: @romainl You were correct, I was answering for vifm, not vim.  Related, but different.  I believe that my new answer is more useful.